# How to use the MaterialSharedAxis Transition in Java

Tags: java, android, material-design, transition

How do I get the MaterialSharedAxis transition as mentioned [here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion/#shared-axis)
**in Java**. You can see that the documentation is in Kotlin I couldn't find a Java documentation for these transitions. I took a look at the library via Android Studio and I could find such a class either. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Transition between Activities

To use `MaterialSharedAxis` you need at less version 1.2.0 of the Material library.
In your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Enable Activity transitions in your theme

```xml
<style  name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
  ...
  <item  name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Activity A:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Slide left
  MaterialSharedAxis sharedAxisExit = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.X,true);
  // Slide right
  MaterialSharedAxis sharedAxisEnter = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.X,false);

  // Exclude this views from the animation, or you get a flicker in animation.
  sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container), true);
  sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
        sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

          sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container), true);
  sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
  sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

  getWindow().setEnterTransition(sharedAxisEnter);
  getWindow().setExitTransition(sharedAxisExit);
}
```

Activity B:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  MaterialSharedAxis sharedAxisEnter = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.X,true);
  MaterialSharedAxis sharedAxisExit = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.X,false);

          sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container), true);
  sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
  sharedAxisEnter.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

          sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container), true);
  sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
  sharedAxisExit.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

  getWindow().setEnterTransition(sharedAxisEnter);
  getWindow().setExitTransition(sharedAxisExit);
}
```

Trigger the animation:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityA.this);
startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialSharedAxis` was introduced in version `1.2.0-alpha05` of the Material library, so you need to use this version (or above) on your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Please note that since this library is in alpha, there might be some breaking changes before a stable release.

---

#### Transition between Fragments

In order to Transition between Fragments, you need to configure it in both Fragments's `onCreate` method.

Fragment A:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  MaterialSharedAxis backward = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, false);
  setReenterTransition(backward);

  MaterialSharedAxis forward = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, true);
  setExitTransition(forward);
}
```

Fragment B:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  MaterialSharedAxis forward = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, true);
  setEnterTransition(forward);

  MaterialSharedAxis backward = new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, false);
  setReturnTransition(backward);
}
```

To move forward from Fragment A to Fragment B:

```java
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentB())
  .commit();
```

---

You should consider learning Kotlin, since it is now the Official language for Android and most libraries, documentation snippets and sample apps are now being written in it.

Comment: How do I do this with activity? Since `window.setExitTransition()` is expecting `android.transition.Transition` while MaterialSharedAxis is inheriting `androidx.transition.Transition`.